# Omnet++ / Data in a pandas cell(list) vs pandas series(column)

Tags: python, pandas, performance, omnet++

So I'm using Omnet++, a discrete time network simulator, to simulate different networking scenarios. At some point one can further process Omnet++ output statistics and store them in a .csv file.

The interesting thing about it is that for each time (`vectime`) there is a value (`vecvalue`). Those vectime/vecvalues are stored in a single cell of such .csv file. When imported into a Pandas Dataframe, I get something like this.

```
In [45]: df1[['module','vectime','vecvalue']]
Out[45]: 
              module                                            vectime                                           vecvalue
237  Tictoc13.tic[1]  [2.542245319062, 3.066965320033, 4.78723506093...  [0.334535581612, 0.390459633837, 0.50391696492...
249  Tictoc13.tic[4]  [2.649303071938, 6.02527384362, 21.42434044990...  [2.649303071938, 1.654927100273, 3.11051622577...
261  Tictoc13.tic[3]  [4.28876656608, 16.104821448604, 19.5989313700...  [2.245250432259, 3.201153958979, 2.39023520069...
277  Tictoc13.tic[2]  [13.884917126016, 21.467263378748, 29.59962616...  [0.411703261805, 0.764708518232, 0.83288346614...
289  Tictoc13.tic[5]  [14.146524815409, 14.349744576545, 24.95022463...  [1.732060647139, 8.66456377103, 2.275388282721...
```

For example, if I needed to plot each vectime/vecvalue for each module, today I'm doing the following...

```
%pylab

def runningAvg(x):
    sigma_x = np.cumsum(x)
    sigma_n = np.arange(1,x.size + 1)
    return  sigma_x / sigma_n

for row in df1.itertuples():
    t = row.vectime
    x = row.vecvalue
    x = runningAvg(x)
    plot(t,x)
```

... to obtain this ...

[image]

My question is: what's best in terms of performance:

- use the data as is, meaning using those arrays inside each cell, looping over the DF to plot each array;
- convert those arrays as pd.Series. In this case, what would be better to still have the module as index?
- would I benefit from unnesting those arrays into pd.Series?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've wondered around and it seems that converting Omnet data into `pd.Series` might not be as efficient as I thought.

These are my two methods:

1) Using Omnet data as is, lists inside Pandas DF.

```
figure(1)

start = datetime.datetime.now()

for row in df1.itertuples():
    t = row.vectime
    x = row.vecvalue
    x = runningAvg(x)
    plot(t,x)

total = (datetime.datetime.now() - start).total_seconds()
print(total)
```

When running the above, the `total` is `0.026571`.

2) Converting Omnet data to `pd.Series`.

To obtain the same result, I had to transpose the series several times.

```
figure(2)

start = datetime.datetime.now()

t = df1.vectime
v = df1.vecvalue
t = t.apply(pd.Series) 
v = v.apply(pd.Series)
t = t.T
v = v.T

sigma_v = np.cumsum(v)
sigma_n = np.arange(1,v.shape[0]+1)
sigma   = sigma_v.T / sigma_n

plot(t,sigma.T)

total = (datetime.datetime.now() - start).total_seconds()
print(total)
```

For the later, `total` is `0.57266`.

So it seems that I'll stick to method 1, looping over the different rows.